# getimagesize() returns false on some images

Tags: php, image, validation, upload, getimagesize

I'm running `getimagesize()` to determine whether or not an uploaded file is a valid image and also it's MIME type. A user of my webapp reported that some of his images where getting an "invalid filetype" error after uploading them. So I asked him to send me some of them to check.

The error string itself is meaningless as it's just a generic text written by me when the functions fails (returns `FALSE`). I tried increasing PHP's memory limit with no success. Also, logs don't show anything unusual. Is there a problem with the files or is it something else? is there a better way to do this operation?

I'm accepting any file that `getimagesize()` accepts (meaning it has a width/height), I'm just checking that it doesn't return `FALSE` (although my real scope would be jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tif|tiff). The server is running PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny3. I repeat, this happens only with the image linked and some others from the same series, so I'm more inclined to think it's related to what Lizard is hinting.

`$_FILES` seems to be empty before getting to `getimagesize($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])` so the file is never really checked. I'll have to figure out why these files are not submitted like the rest (too big for PHP perhaps? any ideas?).

Comment: And what's the code you're using to check/verify the images?

Comment: Your image works for me with PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.1: `Content-type: image/jpeg; size: 2736x3648`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around SO I've found this [insightful answer regarding PHP's upload limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180661/problem-uploading-files-greater-than-10mb-in-ie6/1181258#1181258). I combined it with what I already knew and finally got it working using the following code in my .htaccess (limiting uploads to 5MB):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value post_max_size 8M
php_value max_input_time 1800
LimitRequestBody 0
```

Bottom line is: the problem wasn't in PHP's `getimagesize()` function, it was that the images were never uploaded to the server due to file size limits in both Apache and PHP. Thanks everyone who answered and commented, It would have been a lot more painful to figure it out without your help!

Comment: If the array $_FILES is empty, chances are that $_POST is too so the setting that is *#&%ing you is `post_max_size`. As the upload is being sent with a POST request, is is under the scope of the this setting as well, so PHP empties `$_POST` and as `$_POST` is empty, PHP don't find anything to put inside `$_FILES`.

Answer (score 4):

Until you give more information, I can't really help much. The following code:

```
$file = "http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9159/dsc00799e.jpg";
$info = getimagesize($file);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($info,true) . "</pre>";
```

(Where $file is equal to the location of the image given in the question), outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2736
    [1] => 3648
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="2736" height="3648"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

This seems okay. I'm assuming an error somewhere else in your checks?

Comment: Yeah, same result here with PHP 5.2.3

Comment: I get the same results too, so I'm updating the question, thanks ricebowl and pablasso!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the answer your looking for but I know that I have issues with php functions and images being over 3000px in any dimension.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You said

> $_FILES seems to be empty

Did you check for an upload error? - When the upload fails PHP sets the `error` element of the file's array. See the PHP documentation's [File Upload section](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) for different error codes possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer johannes, however the file wasn't even getting to the script since PHP couldn't handle it due to the imposed upload limits. As I said in my answer, changing these limits made it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, i used exactly the same file reference as used in the img tag:

```
  $filename = "/images/logo.jpg"; 

  $size = getimagesize($filename); // <== this fails

  <img src="<?echo $filename ?>" />  // <== this works
```

When I removed the first slash in the file name and tried it again, it worked:

```
  $size = getimagesize("/images/logo.jpg"); // <== this fails

  $size = getimagesize("images/logo.jpg"); // <== this works!
```

I hope it works for others too.

Comment: This is you getting confused between web paths and disk paths